# Can't use ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized to start Firefox instance minimized?

Tags: .net, firefox

I'm having trouble using Process.Start with Firefox. I want to start a new instance of Firefox in a minimized window. The following works fine with Internet Explorer, notepad, etc.:

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
p.FileName = "iexplore.exe";
p.Arguments = "http://www.google.com";
p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
Process.Start(p);
```

This opens IE in a new, minimized window. Good, just what I want. If I try the exact same thing but instead supply Firefox in the p.FileName, it opens Firefox in a "normal" window, rather than minimized. I've tried various changes to arguments, also have tried examining my local Firefox settings (under Tools/Options) with no luck. I'm sure I'm just missing something simple, but can't figure out what it is. If anyone can help me with getting Firefox opened in a minimized state it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible that Firefox is opening minimized, but upon opening, is "normalizing" itself?

Comment: Yes, I think that's definitely possible. Which would make me think that I would need to change something in my Firefox settings. But, I can't figure out what it would be.

Answer (score 0):

This is a link to an awfully old thread, but it might still be relevant for your issue: [Start Firefox minimized to taskbar?](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=338477&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a).

Comment: Thanks, I did see that one in my searches and I could not get anything along those lines to work. It's referring to a Windows shortcut, which is different than what I'm wanting to do, but it does seem to be basically the same problem.